# Habilitar tecla de "Pesquisa" teclado android

Tags: android, teclado

novamente aqui! Em alguns aplicativos podemos perceber um botão no teclado com o desenho de uma lupa.. esse teclado, ou botão, se faz necessário ser habilitado na aplicação? procurei diversos meios de adicionar o mesmo e criar um evento de pesquisa para ele porém nao obtive sucesso, alguém já passou por alguma situação semelhante?
Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Esse botão no teclado é chamado de `IME`, e você pode configurar (no seu caso) através do atributo `android:imeOptions="actionSearch"`:

```
<EditText 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch" 
    android:inputType="text"/>
```

Para tratar o clique neste botão, você pode utilizar o listener `OnEditorActionListener`:

```
seuEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
            //suas implementações
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Declarar um new TextView mesmo utilizando EditText nao pode dar um conflito?

Comment: @diegofigueiredo não! Na própria documentação (aqui http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) está desta maneira.